# How to use a UPDATE clause and a INSERT clause in the same file?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, pdo

Here is my form in my html page.. the hidden inputs are for the notification INSERT.. and the "text" input & the "range" input are for the UPDATE order progress ALSO the UPDATE statement is working just not the INSERT..

```
<form method="POST" action="../PHP/ordprogress.php">

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fetch['username']?>" name="username">
<input type="hidden" value="Admin" name="name">
<input type="hidden" value="Update!" name="notif">
<input type="hidden" value="Your progress has been updated!" name="details">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); ?>" name="date">
<input type="hidden" value="unread" name="status">

<input type="text" name="uid" value="" placeholder="Order Number..">
<input type="range" step="25" min="0" max="100" value="50" name="ordprogress" class="sliderper" id="myRange">

<button type="submit" value="Update" name="Update">Update</button>
</form>
```

And here is my ordprogress.php script, it should just insert a row (notification) *after* the order progress has been updated..I had it working twice and then I tried to fix something then it stopped working and when I reverted the code it still didn't work lol

```
<?php 
session_start();

require("/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/PHP/connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {

    $ordprogress = $_POST['ordprogress'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];

    $stmt = "UPDATE device_repairs SET ordprogress = :ordprogress WHERE uid = :uid";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ordprogress', $_POST['ordprogress'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $_POST['uid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();


    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $notif = $_POST['notif'];
    $details = $_POST['details'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `notifications` (uid, username, name, notif, details, date, status) VALUES (:uid, :username, :name, :notif, :details, :date, :status)';

    $inst = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                                                              
    $inst->execute(['uid' => $uid, 'username' => $username, 'name' => $name, 'notif' => $notif, 'details' => $details, 'date' => $date, 'status' => $status]);

    ?>

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.mysite.co.uk/Profile/admin.php" />

    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: How is it failing? Are you getting an error? If so, what's the message?

Comment: @Barmar No I am not getting any error, the UPDATE section is working fine but the INSERT section isn't working for some reason

Comment: Do you have `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled, so you get an error if there's a query error?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the insert.

Comment: @Barmar yes I have that in my connect.php file included in the php

Comment: @Barmar its strange because I had it working before

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but you never use the `$ordprogress` or `$uid` variables that you assign before the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Go through your change history to see what you changed.